# Numbers of a certain form not expressible as squares

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello there, I have a problem and would like to know do anyone have an elementary proof of it and it goes like this:

Show that $ a^n + 1\neq m^2$ when $a=4,7,10$ for every $n$ and $m$ ($n$ and $m$ are natural numbers).

EDIT: I succeded in finding an elementary proof that $ a^n + 1\neq m^2$ when $a$ is of the form $a=3k+4$ , $k\geq0$ and I did it using properties of the "digital root" function

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root

First, suppose that $a^n=m^2-1=(m-1)(m+1)$

We have the following cases:

1) $dr(m-1)=1$ imply  $dr(m+1)=3$ which taken together imply $dr((m-1)(m+1))=3$

2) $dr(m-1)=2$ imply $dr(m+1)=4$ which taken together imply $dr((m-1)(m+1))=8$

3) $dr(m-1)=3$ imply $dr(m+1)=5$ which taken together imply $dr((m-1)(m+1))=6$

4) $dr(m-1)=4$ imply $dr(m+1)=6$ which taken together imply $dr((m-1)(m+1))=6$

5) $dr(m-1)=5$ imply $dr(m+1)=7$ which taken together imply $dr((m-1)(m+1))=8$

6) $dr(m-1)=6$ imply $dr(m+1)=8$ which taken together imply $dr((m-1)(m+1))=3$

7) $dr(m-1)=7$ imply $dr(m+1)=9$ which taken together imply $dr((m-1)(m+1))=9$

8) $dr(m-1)=8$ imply $dr(m+1)=1$ which taken together imply $dr((m-1)(m+1))=8$

9) $dr(m-1)=9$ imply $dr(m+1)=2$ which taken together imply $dr((m-1)(m+1))=9$

So we have $dr((m-1)(m+1))\in\lbrace 3,6,8,9 \rbrace$ but since $dr(3k+4)\in\lbrace 1,4,7 \rbrace$ implies that $dr((3k+4)^n)\in\lbrace 1,4,7 \rbrace$ the result follows because $\lbrace 3,6,8,9 \rbrace \cap \lbrace 1,4,7 \rbrace = \emptyset$

Comment: For $n>1$, this is a special case of Catalan's conjecture (proved by Mihailescu). These special cases may well have elementary proofs, search the literature. The case $n=1$ you can do by inspection.

Comment: At least 4 and 7 seem simple, factor $m^2-1=(m+1)(m-1)$ and observe that not both can be a power of 2 (except for $m=3$) or a power of 7, resp. And, what is the motivation for this? Voting to close. 

  

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that Catalan´s conjecture have status of a theorem, and sure there must be some elementary method for proving these three cases.

Comment: Motivation is to find elementary proof when $a$ is of the form $a=3k+4$ when k is natural number, or zero. 

Comment: Close this one, I will post now another question and the fact that I discovered about it.

Comment: No need for posting, the fact that I discovered is easily obtained.

Comment: Your proof can be simplified greatly. If $a=3k+4$, then $a\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, hence $a^n+1\equiv 2\pmod{3}$. On the other hand, it is easy to see that $m^2\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ is impossible.

Comment: Note that "digital root" is just a small variation of "residue modulo 9".

Comment: Is it possible to attack this with modular arithmetic?

Solve in positive integers, with $n\geq9$


$81k^2+18k-n!=0$ and

$81k^2-18k-n!=0$

Comment: These are two problems, not a system of equations

Comment: Solving your last two equations is equivalent to solving $n!+1=m^2$. In general, for any odd $q>1$, there is an effective $n_0$ such that $n\geq n_0$ and $n!+1=m^2$ imply $m=kq\pm 1$ for some integer $k$. Your equations correspond to $q=9$. BTW your questions are not of research level, hence off-topic here.

Comment: I forgot to say: the integral solutions of $n!+1=m^2$ are not known at the moment (I believe).

Comment: See the wikipedia entry for Brocard's Problem, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard's_problem

Comment: Sorry, the hyphen in the url seems to mess up the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend this [survey](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2004-41-01/S0273-0979-03-00993-5/S0273-0979-03-00993-5.pdf) about the solution of Catalan's conjecture. We learn from here that the special case you are considering, namely $x^p-y^q=1$ for $p=2$, was solved by Chao Ko in 1964. In 1976 Chein published a simpler proof, see [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-056-01/S0002-9939-1976-0404133-1/S0002-9939-1976-0404133-1.pdf).

Comment: I commented above (and then mistakenly deleted) that the specific result desired by the poster was realized through mod 3 considerations.  I suspect that the poster is even more interested in when elementary considerations provide quick answers.  For example, knowing when 2 is not a qth power mod a covers the cases mentioned and many more.  Gerhard "Looks For Really Simple Answers" Paseman, 2013.01.28

Comment: As a general aside: there is also a technically non-elementary (but in certain ways simpler) proof by Mignotte "A new proof of Ko Chao's theorem" (2004)

Comment: Also, while I presently do not see how to  improve on Chein's argument, I still think that something simpler and possibly less complete is wanted. Gerhard "AskMe About System Design" Paseman, 2013.01.28

Comment: I found an elementary proof that $a^n + 1\neq m^2$ when $a$ is of the form $a=3k+4$. In it I used the properties of this function: 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigitalRoot.html

Thank you all for your valuable information.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to include your elementary proof in your original post.

Comment: @Antisha: As Gerhard Paseman says if you consider your equation modulo $3$ (for your $a$) you get $1^n+1= m^2$ modulo $3$, which cannot have a solution as any square is $0$ or $1$ modulo $3$ and not $2$. 

Comment: Oh well I did it in different way, look now when it is edited.

Comment: Your proof can be simplified greatly, see my comment to your original post.

Comment: Ah well, I see quid and Gerhard Paseman told you the same.